# Fill a symmetric matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

having a trouble with a condition which tells if an element of a multidimensional array 
as example **arr[row][col]** is exactly **arr[col][row]** then automatically assign the value of arr[col][row] to the same value of arr[row][col] **without letting user enter it manually**

That should be an example of the output

```
example[4][4] = 
     {
     //   0   1   2   3
        { 0, 10, 15, 18},   //   0
        { 10, 0, 20, 14},   //   1
        { 15, 20, 0, 90},   //   2
        { 18, 14,90, 0},    //   3
```

here's my code

```
`   int size;
    int arr[size][size];
    cout<<"Choose size of your multidimensional array [matrix]: ",cin>>size;
    cout<<"Now enter your data [Respectively] \n";
    for(int d=0 ; d<size ; d++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (d==j) 
            {
                arr[d][j]=0 ;
            }
            else if(arr[d][j]!=0 ) //there should be the problem
            {
                arr[j][d]=arr[d][j];
            }
            else
            {
                cin>>arr[d][j]; // Filling matrix
            }
        }
    }  `
```

Comment: `&arr[d][j]==&arr[j][d]` --> `arr[d][j]== arr[j][d]`. Why are you comparing the addresses? Also, `int arr[size][size]` is not valid c++.

Comment: `int arr[size][size];` here `size` is used uninitialized

Comment: Note that VLA:s (variable-length arrays) aren't part of standard C++. [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: well initializing my array that way  >> int arr[size][size]; actually worked, it's just that i don't get my desired output

Comment: Yeah that's my problem , I actually want to assign that rr[j][d]=arr[d][j];
after checking if  rr[d][j] is equal to something , 
that part should be erased && arr[d][j]==arr[j][d]

Comment: @Gradzidsa when you declare the matrix `arr` the value of `size` is completely random, when you do `cin>>size` the matrix is already allocated, updating the value of `size` does not affect `arr`

Comment: _"well (code used undefined behavior) actually worked"_  That's the funny thing about **undefined behavior**.  It can even sometimes appear to work, which is the most insidious of all.

Comment: @Gradzidsa If you want the program to be portable, don't use `int arr[size][size];`. Instead, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(size, std::vector<int>(size));`

Comment: well i'm removing && arr[d][j]==arr[j][d] because it doesn't make any sense 
but still there is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Minimum Working Example (MWE) that should solve your issues:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Choose size of your multidimensional array [matrix]: ";
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int arr[size][size];
    cout << "Now enter your data [Respectively] \n";
    for(int d=0; d<size; d++)
    {
        for(int j=d+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (d==j)
            {
                arr[d][j] = 0;
            }
            else if(j<d)      // here laid the problem
            {
                arr[d][j] = arr[j][d];
            }
            else
            {
                cin >> arr[d][j]; // Filling matrix
            }
        }
    }

    // print matrix
    for(int d=0; d<size; d++) {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
            cout << arr[d][j] << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }

return 0;
}
```

This below is even cleaner, gets rid of the conditional inside the inner loop, thank you @ThomasSablik

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Choose size of your multidimensional array [matrix]: ";
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int arr[size][size];
    cout << "Now enter your data [Respectively] \n";

    for(int d=0 ; d<size ; d++)
    {
        arr[d][d]=0;
        for(int j=d+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[d][j];
            arr[j][d]=arr[d][j];
        }
    }

    // print matrix
    for(int d=0; d<size; d++) {
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
            cout << arr[d][j] << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<size; j++)` => `for(int j=d; j<size; j++)` and `cin >> arr[d][j];` => `cin >> arr[d][j]; arr[j][d] = arr[d][j];` allows removing the second case.

Comment: Well your solution gave me a great hint and managed to do a small edit thanks !!

Comment: @ThomasSablik : thank you, very clever, we can even get rid of conditionals altogether by prepending `arr[d][d]=0;` to the second inner `for` loop.

Comment: @Gradzidsa: glad to be of help! You should tick my answer as the accepted one if it has solved your issue, the green 'V' tick besides it, thank you.